# MySQL MATCH for more than one field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT * FROM  portfolio
INNER JOIN  translation 
ON portfolio.description =  translation.key
WHERE
  MATCH(it_translation.*) AGAINST('test')
```

Why this code doesn't work?

If I do like this `MATCH(it_translation.field) AGAINST('test')` everything is ok, but I wanna search FULLTEXT via more than one field, and I don't know how many fields in table.

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html)?  `"The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some FULLTEXT index definition for the table..."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC for FULLTEXT to work you need a FULLTEXT index that covers every field you want to use it for, so if you "don't know how many fields in table" you won't be able to MATCH it like that.